# Is there a way to display all data in Algolia index as list in html?

Tags: firebase, mobile, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I want to display all the data in my Angolia index as a list in an html page. I'm mirroring the Angolia database with Firestore, and currently have it working so my Firestore data can be displayed, but I want to pull the data from Algolia instead, and then maybe filter it.

Feed

```
<ais-instantsearch [config] = "searchConfig">

  <ais-search-box (change)="searchChanged($event)"></ais-search-box>

  <ais-hits *ngIf="showResults">

    <ng-template let-hits="hits">

        <div *ngFor="let hit of hits">

          <div>
            {{hit.description}}
          </div>

        </div>


    </ng-template>

  </ais-hits>

</ais-instantsearch>
```

This is what I have working for searching over my Algolia data, and it works. But I want there to always be displayed all of the data I'm searching over in the html as soon as the page loads.

Comment: From what I've understood you want to display the full content of your index is it correct?

Comment: yes, that's the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the number of records inside your index. You can control how many records the engine returns with the parameters [`hitsPerPage`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/hitsPerPage/). You can provide this parameter with the [`ais-configure`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/angular/) widget.

Note that by default [`hitsPerPage`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/hitsPerPage/) cannot go over 1000. You can increase this limit with the settings [`paginationLimitedTo`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/paginationLimitedTo/). You cannot set this value from InstantSearch. It must be either a call to [`setSettings`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/set-settings/) or update the value inside the Algolia dashboard.

This solution applies to InstantSearch, with the limitation to have a small amount of records in the index. For some use cases this is not a viable solution. You can opt-out from InstantSearch to use the [`browse`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse) method. It allows you to get the full content of your index without any restrictions on the number of records. You can find more information [in the documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/manage-your-indices/how-to/exporting-index-data-to-a-file/).